# Contour lines/ basement contour extraction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, elevation, contour

My purpose: getting out area between elevation contours (like b/w 600m and 700m). The contours could either be elevation ones or the basement contours. I got elevation contours using spatial analyst tool on DEM in ArcMap but they are in the form of polyline and highly dense. I  need it for entire Maharashtra, India. Also "seismotectonic atlas of India" don't have basement contours of Deccan region.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3528bd72847c439f88190a137a1d0e67) tool box. It has a tool that allows you to create filled contours, from which you can easily work out areas.